# Error in use of static inner classes in Program Development in Java by Liskov and Guttag

Tags: java

In Program Development in Java by Liskov and Guttag, they use static inner classes to implement Iterators (section 6.4, pg 134-136). They justify the use of the static inner classes by saying "its code can access private instance variables and methods of [enclosing type] objects." But this (being able to access fields of enclosing objects) is not true of static inner classes, only nested inner classes, correct?

Answer (score 1):

A static inner class can access private members, see for example:

```
public class Main {

    private int i = 5;

    static class B {
        public void print (Main m) {
            System.out.println(m.i);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new B().print(new Main());
    }

}
```

Comment: But this requires a reference to the enclosing object. To me, wouldn't it be more natural to have it be a nested inner class (for example, in the case of Iterators)?

Comment: Probably yes, but this wasn't the question.